# Get currently authorised user in RESTful .NET 4.5 API

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, asp.net-4.5

I am using the individual user accounts part of .NET 4.5 to authenticate and authorise users to a RESTful API (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

However, I need to work out how to access the user ID from the bearer authorisation token, so I can return the data for the correct user.

How do I determine the correct user ID in a stateless API?

Comment: Once WebAPI has accepted the Bearer token and authenticated/authorised the user, you can just use `User.Identity` to get the user name from within the Controller code.

Comment: Thank you. Was struggling with no HTTPContext there for a minute...I presume I'll have the relevant namespace already loaded.

Comment: Yes, `User` is a member of `ApiController` so you shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: Do you want to add that as the answer and I'll tick and vote it! ;-)

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once WebAPI has accepted the Bearer token and authenticated/authorised the user, you can just use `User.Identity` to get the user name from within the API Controller code:

e.g.

```
// GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
           var userName = User.Identity.Name;
           //and so on...
        }
```